# read XML document using listbox

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

i have a xml document named sms.xml where data is stored like this:

```
<sms address="+995555777777" time="Mar 12, 2013 5:08:09 PM" date="1363093689732" type="2" body="blah blah blah? :D" read="1" service_center="" name="name surname" />
```

it's one sms and i have more than 1000 sms, so i want to load them in listbox by name, or address (it doesn't matter) and when i click one of them i want to show the body of selected sms. this is my code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    public void loadXML()
    {
        xmlDoc.Load("sms.xml");

        XmlNodeList smss = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//sms");

        foreach (XmlNode sms in smss)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(sms.Attributes["address"].Value);
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadXML();
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("sms[@name='{0}']", listBox1.SelectedItem));

        txtName.Text = node.Attributes["body"].Value;

    }
```

and it returns error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on a txtName.text line. can you help?

p.s. sorry for my English.

Comment: you are adding them to the box by address and then using an xpath attribute selector for name. change @ name to @ address and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a syntax issue, try the following:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//sms[@name='{0}']", listBox1.SelectedItem));
    txtName.Text = node.Attributes["body"].Value;
}
```

Note the leading `//`.

Comment: :aaaaaaaaaaaaa: i hate it when chars like this get all code to fail. thanks man, it works now.

Comment: there is one problem: from one sender it shows the same message every time, not the real message text body when the list in listbox is shown by name, but when i show it with time, everything works fine. is there any way to work it by name?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you try to rephrase?

Comment: in xml there is attributes, such as name, date, time etc. when i'm adding messages into listbox by attribute 'name' it only shows one message body, form every message sent from one person. for example: mary sent me 5 messages, with different text. in this case it only shows last messages text (body). but when i add items in listbox by time, it works fine, shows each mesages body (text).

Comment: If I understand correctly, no matter what message you select for Mary, you always see the same text.  In which case your problem is that you need to specify the index of the sms that corresponds with the selecteditem.  For example if you selected the 3rd message from Mary you want the sms at index 2 that matches @name = "Mary".